# Using an Inner Join and returning only 1 record per match on the left

Tags: sql, join

I don't know why I'm not able to figure this out ATM.  [Here's a very contrived example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2efb9/3).

```
create table Dog (
  [Name] varchar(10), 
  [BreedId] int
);

create table Breed (
  [BreedId] int,
  [Name] varchar(10)
);

insert into DOG (name, breedid)
VALUES ('Mix', 1),
  ('Mix2', 2),
  ('Mix2', 3);

insert into breed(breedid, name)
VALUES 
  (1, 'BullDog'),
  (1, 'Poodle'),
  (2, 'BullDog'),
  (2, 'Poodle'),
  (4, 'Poodle');
```

The following produces two rows because the join table has two matching values, I just want one value *as long as there is a matching record on the right*.

```
select d.*
from dog d
inner join breed b on d.breedid = b.breedid
```

results in:

> Mix   1
>
> Mix   1
>
> Mix   2
>
> Mix   2

Is there a way to do this **in the join clause** / **without** doing a `select` in the where clase or other options like group by.

```
select d.*
from dog d
where d.breedid in (select breedid from breed)
```

Comment: My preferred way Erik is to use a derived table which rownumbers each potential match, and then use the join condition to select only the first match. It's my preferred approach when trying to limit the number of rows joined on the right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: @philipxy I don't know why you're commenting on my consideration of asking a question.  I've asked 40 questions and answered over 1,300 and have revised over 5,800 questions over the past decade.  I'm fully aware of how to ask a question.

Comment: Clearly not. See my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "select distinct". You can also group by the columns that are duplicates and take the max() of columns that have unique values.

**Edit**: how to filter by breed.breedid without using a where clause.

```
select d.*
From dog as d
Inner join (select distinct breedid from breed) as b on b.breedid = d.breedid
```

Comment: While this works, the actual SQL is so complex, that `group by` would only make the sql harder to read.

Comment: @philipxy I suggest you drop the *judging* of peoples capabilities an actually try to help.

Comment: @ErikPhilips What I told you was to help, if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists` if you only want columns from `dog`:

```
select d.*
from dog d
where exists (select 1 from breed b where d.breedid = b.breedid);
```

Comment: is there a way to do this in the Join Clause?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Google re inner join conditions in where vs on. Another obviously trivially found faq.